# Configuring the OpenSocial Gadget with a DLFileEntry

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, google-gadget, opensocial, document-library

I'm trying to configure the OpenSocial Gadget Container with an xml file within the Document Library.
My code actually is:

```
public String getDLFilePath(long entryId){
    DLFileEntry dlEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getDLFileEntry(entryId);

        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)rReq.getAttribute( WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);        
        String pathDocumentLibrary=themeDisplay.getPortalURL()  
                + themeDisplay.getPathContext()  
                + "/documents/"
                + themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()
                + StringPool.SLASH;

        return pathDocumentLibrary+dlEntry.getUuid();
}
```

But the gadget container say me that

> URL does not point to a valid gadget.

The filepath returned by the function is correct (because if I put it in the browser addressbar the file download starts), so I don't understand the reason why I can't configure the Gadget.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I needed to set Guest VIEW permissions on the file and all parent folders including the root folder.

Liferay version: 6.2 EE